# Computation of residue class of $2^{100}$ modulo $1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

$2^{100} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod}\ 125)$ and is divisible by $8$. Why then is $2^{100} \equiv 376 \ (\text{mod}\ 1000)$?

Comment: What is divisible by $8$? $2^{100}$?

Comment: $2^{11} \equiv 2048 \equiv 48 \pmod{1000} \implies 2^{100} \equiv (2^{11})^9 \cdot 2 \equiv 48^9 \cdot 2 \equiv 2705210921189376 \equiv 376 \pmod{1000}$

Comment: @Aniket Yes. Intended meaning: "$2^{100}$ is equivalent to $1$ modulo $125$ and is divisible by $8$".

Comment: $2^{100}=2^{3\times 33+1}=2\times 8^{33}$ is indeed divisible by $8$

Comment: $2^{25} \equiv 33554432 \equiv 432 \pmod{1000} \implies 2^{100} \equiv (2^{25})^4 \equiv 432^4 \cdot 2 \equiv 34828517376 \equiv 376 \pmod{1000}$

Comment: So you need to solve $x\equiv 0 \pmod{128}$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$ So $x = 8y$ and $8y \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$, that is, $x = 8y$ and $y = 47$. Hence $x = 376$.

Comment: @StevenGregory I suggest  you add your comment as an answer, it is an interestign way to find the value.  Bu the way, in your first line, maybe you have a typo and it should be  $8$  and not  $128$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

> If   ($a\equiv b \mod{c}$)  &  ($ a\equiv b \mod{d}$) &   ($c$ and  $d$ are coprime), then  $a\equiv b \mod{dc}$

As $8= 2^3$  and  $125=5^3$  are coprime, and  $8*125=1000$, then to find $2^{100} \mod{1000}$,   it is enough to find the  smallest $b$ such that $2^{100}\equiv b \mod{125}$ and $2^{100}\equiv b \mod{8}$. 
We have  $2^{100}\equiv 0 \mod{8}$, and $2^{100}\equiv 1 \mod{125}$, moreover
$$2^{100}\equiv 1\equiv 126\equiv 251\equiv 376\equiv 501 \equiv 626\equiv 751\equiv 876 \mod{125}$$
and
$$2^{100}\equiv 0\equiv 8 \equiv 120 \equiv 248\equiv 376  \mod{8}$$

Thus our $b$ is equal to $376$.

Comment: Shouldn't $bc = cd$ in the displayed line?

Comment: Why you think so  @RandyRanderson ?

Comment: Because that's what you used in the rest of the answer... $c = 125$, $d = 8$.

Comment: @Nizar $d$ is never used in the displayed line as it currently goes so it might be a typo.

Comment: I mean the yellow box.

Comment: @cr001 Okay , I see it , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of all numbers congruent to $1$ modulo $125$ and less than $1000$:
$$1,\ 126,\ 251,\ 376,\ 501,\ 626,\ 751,\ 876,$$ 
only $376$ is a multiple of $8$.

Answer (score 0):

$1000 = 2^3 \times 5^3 = 8 \times 125$

$2^{100} \equiv 8 \times 2^{97} \equiv 0 \pmod 8$

$\varphi(125)=5^3 - 5^2 = 100$,
so $2^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$

We need to find $x$ such that $x \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$.

$x \equiv 0 \pmod 8 \implies x = 8y$ for some integer $y$.
$x \equiv 1 \pmod{125} \implies 8y \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$

```
    | 125   1     0  {125 =  (1)125 +   (0)8}
-15 |   8   0     1  {  8 =  (0)125 +   (1)8}
 -2 |   5   1   -15  {  5 =  (1)125 + (-15)8}
  2 |  -2  -2    31  { -2 = (-2)125 +  (31)8}
    |   1  -3    47  {  1 = (-3)125 +  (47)8}
```

$8y \equiv 1 \pmod{125}
\implies y \equiv 47 \pmod{125}
\implies x \equiv 376 \pmod{1000}$